# How to encode base 64 to .kml file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, base64, kml, data-conversion

I convert kml file to base 64. Now I want to encode base 64 to become kml file again? is this possible? I convert kml file like this..

```
        $scope.myFunction = function () {
        var files = document.getElementById('myFile').files;
        if (files.length > 0) {
            getBase64(files[0]);
        }
    }

    function getBase64(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = function () {
            console.log(reader.result);
        };
        reader.onerror = function (error) {
            console.log('Error: ', error);
        };
    }
```

how can I store kml file to database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a Blob from a base64 string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript)

Comment: why do you event want to convert it to base64?

Answer (score 1):

It surely is possible, you just have to decode the base64 and turn the result into a file again.

```
function base64ToFile(base64){

  content=atob(base64);
  var file = new Blob([content], {type: 'kml'});

  //You can now asign the file to a link to download, send it with ajax, etc..

  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);

}
```

Bear in mind, that you cant write a file directly onto disk from javascript, because that would be a security issue, you need t

Comment: Thank so much sir, sir follow up question i want to view this kml in google map. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml i want to change this kml file

Comment: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded. error sir

Comment: You need to make sure the base64 string you are providing the function its a correctly formatted base64 string, if you send the base64 string you are getting back from your function,  i can try to see whats wrong.

Comment: is my code in converting kml file to base 64 is wrong?